# Install Phalcon on RHEL 7

Tags: phalcon, rhel7

I'm trying to install Phalcon on my RHEL 7 VM. I downloaded files and folders from GitHub and place them on my VM via WinSCP in `/opt/` (using remi repo or `git clone` from VM is blocked)

When I move into `/opt/phalcon/build/` and try to `sudo ./install`, I got a notice that PHP 5 is no longer supported, currently on my Red Hat, I have PHP 7.3.11 version running (checked using `php -v` and config page).

I installed things like php-devel or gcc.

I have rh-php73-php installed and running on my VM

Maybe someone can help me, because I have no idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have rh-php73-php installed and running on my VM

Sorry, but phalcon extension package doesn't exist for this PHP stack.

Using the full **php** stack from "remi-php73" repository or **php73** SCL from "remi-safe" will give you "php-phalcon4" package with latest version of this extension.

> using remi repo or git clone from VM is blocked

Use a proxy, or download packages and install them manually.

Tips: test installation from another computer, connected to internet, to get the full package list. You can even retrieve them later from /var/cache/yum (using keepcache=1 in yum.conf)

For memory, for a proper installation, follow the [Wizard instructions](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/)